# Pandas vectorization with two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

assume I have the following two dataframes. DataFrame A and DataFrame B.

DataFrame A has four columns. Year, Month, day and temperature. (e.g. 2021 || 7 || 5 || 23). Currently, some of the temperature cell in DataFrame A are NaN.

DataFrame B has two columns. Date and temperature. (e.g. 2021/7/7 || 28)

The time interval of DataFrame A and DataFrame B are different. The time interval of DataFrame A is smaller than interval B. But some of them overlap. (e.g. every 10 mins in DataFrame B and every 5 mins in DataFrame A).

Now I want to copy the temperature data from DataFrame B to DataFrame A if there is a NaN value in DataFrame A.

I have a method which using looping, but it is very slow. I want to use pandas vectorization. But I don't know how. Can anyone teach me?

```
    for i in tqdm(range(len(dfA['Temp']))):
       if(pd.isna(df['Temp'].iloc[i])):
         date_time_str = str(year) + '/' + str(month) + '/' + str(day)
         try:
            dfA['temp'].iloc[i] = float(dfB.loc[dfB['Date'] == date_time_str].iloc[:, 1])
            
         except:
            print("no value")
            pass
```

My solution is very slow, how to do it with pandas vectorization?

**Method I tried for vectorization:**

```
dfA.loc[df['temp'].isnull() & ((datetime.datetime(dfA['Year'], df['*Month'], dfA['Day']).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"))in dfB.Date.values) , 'temp'] = float(dfB[dfB['Date'] == datetime.datetime(dfA['Year'], df['*Month'], dfA['Day']].iloc[:, 1])
```

Above is my method and trying, it doesn't work.

**Example data:**

```
DataFrame A
Year    Month   Day Temperature
2020    1        17  25
2020    1        18  NaN
2020    1        19  28
2020    1        20  NaN
2020    1        21  NaN
2020    1        22  NaN

DataFrame B
Date    Temp
1/17/2020   25
1/19/2020   28
1/21/2020   31
1/23/2020   34
1/25/2020   23
1/27/2020   54

Expected Output
Year    Month   Day Temperature
2020    1        17 25
2020    1        18 NaN
2020    1        19 28
2020    1        20 NaN
2020    1        21 31
2020    1        22 NaN
```

[image]

Comment: @Chirs, I add some sample data, please check, thank you

Comment: @Chris, I just change the sample data, please check, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's map them:

```
dfa['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dfa[['Day','Month','Year']])
dfb['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dfb['Date'])
dfb['Temperature']=dfa.pop('Date').map(dfb.set_index('Date')['Temp'])
```

OR

Let's Merge them:

```
dfa['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dfa[['Day','Month','Year']])
dfb['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dfb['Date'])
dfa=dfa.merge(dfb[['Date','Temp']],on='Date',how='left')
dfa['Temperature']=dfa['Temperature'].fillna(dfa.pop('Temp'))
```

Comment: @Arurag Dabas, I found that it should be `dfa.pop('Temp')`. I think I just made a mistake so I deleted the comment. Because we merge dfa and dfb. dfa now has the column 'temp'. So we can pop the value from dfa['temp'], after that write it to dfa['Temperature']. 

I am not sure, can you help me you confirm my answer is correct. Thank you so much

Comment: @Stack ohh....then updated answer....yes you are right since we are assigning the merge operation to dfa variable so it's `dfa.pop('Temp')` **:)**

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pandas.to_datetime` with `pandas.Series.fillna`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df1[["Year", "Month", "Day"]]))
s = df2.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df2.pop("Date"))).squeeze()
df1["Temperature"] = df1["Temperature"].fillna(s)
print(df1.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   Year  Month  Day  Temperature
0  2020      1   17         25.0
1  2020      1   18          NaN
2  2020      1   19         28.0
3  2020      1   20          NaN
4  2020      1   21         31.0
5  2020      1   22          NaN
```